# Is it possible to add custom fields to Word Press pages, similar to custom meta boxes for posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

For Word Press posts you can add custom meta boxes, and these can be targeted easily in the front end. E.g. if I had a description meta box I could write

```
<?php echo ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_description', true ) ); ?>
```

To display that field.

Is it possible to add custom boxes like this to pages? So if I wanted to have a field for "Hero Image" I would be able to display it using something similar to this -

```
<img src="<?php echo ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_hero-image', true ) ); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: yes.  You may hook any post_save function and store whatever meta data you would like to against the post_id (pages are just another custom post really).

I would highly recommend ACF (Advanced Custom Fields).  The pro version is available on GitHub as it is Open Source (GPL License).  With ACF, you can easily use function like: `get_field()` and `the_field()` while providing you the ability to click-to-create many fields and tune the conditions by which they are shown in the Admin Dashboard.